# QTextEdit's QTextDocument failing to resize page after SetText

Tags: python, qtextedit, pyside2

Disclaimer: I am using `PySide2`; however, any answer in Qt (`pyqt5`, `Qt` c++) is fine.

I am having an issue with setting the size of my document in a textedit.

When I initialize a `QTextEdit` with `setText(text:QString)`, the sizing behavior of `QTextEdit`'s `QTextDocument` changes. Consequentially applying `setPageSize` is ignored, unless the text bleeds over the widget's viewport.

If I do not `setText` initially, then the document sizing is correctly accounted for, whether or not I resize the window.

Below is a minimal example of the strange behaviour I've been experiencing. If you run the code, then try resizing the window and you will see the pageSize is accounted for when the text exceeds the widget; however, if not then the `QTextEdit`'s pageSize will match its width and its height be -1.

If you turn off `SET_TEXT_TEST` then there are no problems from the get go. If there are any explanations or workarounds I would love to hear.

```
import PySide2
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtPrintSupport import *

SET_TEXT_TEST = True


class IPageEdit(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # these lines don't seem to do anything
        doc = self.document()
        pageSize = QPageSize(QPageSize.A6).size(QPageSize.Point)
        doc.setPageSize(QPageSize(QPageSize.A6).size(QPageSize.Point))

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        doc = self.document()
        pageSize = QPageSize(QPageSize.A6).size(QPageSize.Point)
        doc.setPageSize(QPageSize(QPageSize.A6).size(QPageSize.Point))

        print('({},{})  ({},{})'.format(
            pageSize.width(),
            pageSize.height(),
            doc.pageSize().width(),
            doc.pageSize().height()))

        painter = QPainter(self.viewport())
        doc.drawContents(painter)


class IMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.resize(1000, 500)
        self.setContentsMargins(20, 20, 20, 20)

        pageEdit = IPageEdit(self)
        if SET_TEXT_TEST:
            pageEdit.setText('''\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum. Metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel. Massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin. Enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper. Leo duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa id neque. Cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat. Eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis. Nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh. Tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa enim nec dui nunc. Eget nullam non nisi est sit amet. Sed odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean sed. Nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam id leo. Adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit. Sed sed risus pretium quam. Elit pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus. Turpis egestas sed tempus urna.

Nunc aliquet bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque. Condimentum id venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant. Purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum. Ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit. Dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel. Donec adipiscing tristique risus nec. Non consectetur a erat nam. Fusce id velit ut tortor pretium. Sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna. Vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas. Ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque.

Turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in ante metus. Nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam id leo. Amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet. Sit amet porttitor eget dolor. Nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi. Turpis massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit. Ac odio tempor orci dapibus. Et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer. Morbi quis commodo odio aenean. Vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada. Lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus.

Tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc sed augue. Etiam sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed. Nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi. Nibh tortor id aliquet lectus proin. Venenatis urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in. Volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit. Magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Lacinia quis vel eros donec ac odio tempor. Justo donec enim diam vulputate. Fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. In dictum non consectetur a erat nam at. Egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta lorem. Scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci. Lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a. Faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt. Habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat. Enim sed faucibus turpis in.

Eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit. Dui id ornare arcu odio. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Senectus et netus et malesuada fames. Porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum. Amet est placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod. Mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget. Tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa enim nec. Pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla. Ut consequat semper viverra nam libero.
''')
        self.setCentralWidget(pageEdit)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wnd = IMainWindow()
    wnd.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

To demonstrate here are a few images:

Page size width as ~1000
[image: Wide Window]

Page size width as 623.0
[image: Window A No Wrap]

Page size width as 622.0
[image: Window A Wrapped]

Comment: I observe the same behavior in both cases, you could show images of both cases.

Comment: To always get the text at the desired width you could try `QTextEdit.setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit.FixedPixelWidth)` in combination with `QTextEdit.setLineWrapColumnOrWidth()` in `IPageEdit.__init__()`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Heike 's response, the solution was as simple as adding this line of code:

```
class IPageEdit(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit.FixedPixelWidth)
        ...
```

This yields the correct resizing behavior and the pageSize retains its value after resizing.